# Please give a simple example of counting

Tags: javascript, algorithm

How many days till a penny doubled everyday will be $10,000 in Javascript and Python?

```
var count = 0
for (var i=0; i<10000; i++) {
    count += 1
}
```

The above code is the response I am looking for.  I am a beginner level and find that knowing simple solutions sometimes help solve bigger problems.

Comment: So if the code you posted is the code you are looking for, what's your question for us?

Comment: That code is already simple enough.

Comment: Technically you're not doubling the value in the loop, try starting at `count = 1` and then using `count *= 2` in the loop (instead of adding 1 each time, it's multiplying by 2 each time)

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution in Python as asked in question.

```
pennies = 1
days = 0 
while (pennies < 10000*100) : 
    pennies *= 2
    days += 1
print ( days , 'days to reach 10000')
```

Comment: wrong! you have a penny($0.01) and need to make $10000

Comment: ya sorry my fault. i didn't know about pennies.

Answer (score 1):

```
var pennies_total = 1 // total amount of pennies
var days_total = 1    // days past
var pennies = 1       // doubled amount for the current day

while (pennies_total < 10000*100) {
    pennies *= 2              // doubling pennies for current day
    pennies_total += pennies  // adding the doubled pennies to the total
    days_total += 1           // increasing the days count
}

print days_total
```

Comment: is it python or javascript. I guess you have mixed up both ;)

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand if this is a question or not as you say "The above code is the response I am looking for". Because the code doesn't answer to the question "How many days till a penny doubled everyday will be $10,000 in Javascript and Python?" I assume yes.

```
pennies = 1
days = 0

while ((pennies / 100) < 10000):

    pennies *= 2
    days += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking how to find how many times it takes to double the value up to 10,000 then you want to change up your looping condition and what you do in your loop.

```
var count = 1; // Start at 1 because we "have 1 penny" already
var i; // Define an index in this scope to keep track of times doubled
for (i=0; count < 10000; i++) { // Check that the penny count is less than 10,000... not the number of iterations
    count *= 2; // Multiply the current value of count by 2
}
console.log(i); // Print # times that the penny was doubled
console.log(count); // Print the value of count (it might not be 10,000 exactly)
```

And if you want a more efficient and accurate solution you could always perform a base 2 logarithm:

```
Math.log2(10000); // 13.287712376549449
```

And to get an integer, just `Math.ceil()` it (because technically if you go over - even a tiny amount - you need to double once more to hit that value).

```
Math.ceil(Math.log2(10000)); // 14
```

Finally, if you were just looking for the number: it takes 14 days to have at least 10,000 pennies